# Chrome 1px line bug

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am making one fan-site and have very stupid bug on news bar. When I zoom the page, 1px line appears.

[image: Example image]

This is the code:

```
<div class="velikibar">
<div id="velikibar_h">
    <div id="naslovbar"><?=$naslov?></div>
</div>
<div id="velikibar_b">
    <div class="paddingvelikibar">
    <?=$sadrzaj?>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="velikibar_f">
    <div id="fblikedugme"><?=$vreme?><br /><div class="fb-like" data-href="http://********.**/article.php?id=<?=$id?>" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false"></div></div>
    <div id="komentarbarbox"><a href="article.php?id=<?=$id?>" target="_self">Komentari (<?=$brkomentara?>)</a></div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS (http://tny.cz/d9fb11db):

```
.velikibar
{
    background-color:transparent;
    width: 652px;
}

#velikibar_h
{
    background-image:url('slike/velikibar_h.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 652px;
    height: 109px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#velikibar_b
{
    background-image:url('slike/velikibar_b.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    width: 652px;
    min-height: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#velikibar_f
{
    background-image:url('slike/velikibar_f.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 652px;
    height: 112px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#velikibar_f2
{
    background-image:url('slike/velikibar_f2.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 652px;
    height: 112px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.paddingvelikibar
{
    padding: 5px 35px 5px 30px;
    text-align:justify;
    color: #fff5f9;
}

#fblikedugme
{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 35px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    color:#fff5f9;
    line-height: 20px;
}

#komentarbarbox
{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 425px;
    margin-top: 65px;
}

#komentarbarbox a, #komentarbarbox a:link, #komentarbarbox a:visited
{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #6f1c3f;
    color: #fdd2e4; 
    text-decoration:none;
}

#komentarbarbox a:hover, #komentarbarbox a:focus
{
    color: #d61566;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#naslovbar
{
font: 23px/1.4em arial, helvetica;
color: #e1aec4;
padding-top: 50px;
padding-left: 35px;
text-shadow: #FCFCFC 0px 1px 0px;
}

.paddingvelikibar img
{
    background-color: #fff2f7;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    behavior: url("skripte/ie-css3.htc");
    padding: 4px;
}
```

Please help me how to fix this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Note: naslov means title, sadržaj means content, vreme means time.

Comment: Thanks, but PHP variables aren't very important here.

Comment: They are *very* important, if people want to see the correspondence between the HTML and the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a browser bug.

For example, an element which is 5px wide, viewed on 1.5 zoom would be 7.5px wide, but the browser has to round it to full pxls so something like this can happen.

To make sure it doesnt happen you can make the elements overlap, or in your case, best would be not to split the pink background image in 2 elements, but have a single element carry the whole image.

Chrome doesnt use font-resize as zoom option, so it is very unlikely that this is caused by a particullar line of css.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, but I can't merge pink bacground images because I can't know height before I write an article.

Comment: @user1261598 Simply make a 1px height background image and use repeat-y

Comment: I use that already and I get this line as you see on picture.

Comment: Then make the repeat-y part have a z-index less than the top bar part and increase the height of the repeating background div with 2px (and decrease the position top with 2px). Sorry for reopening such an old topic, but as it was edited 6 minutes ago it appeared at the top of the list

Comment: This is now fixed in the latest Chrome version (I have 109.0.5414.120). The bug is commented here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/paint-dev/c/ERXM1sHcpyQ